# Prepending Downsample layer to Resnet50 Pretrained Model

Tags: keras

I am using keras 1.1.1 in windows 7 with tensorflow backend.

I am trying to prepend the stock Resnet50 pretained model with an image downsampler.  Below is my code.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
import keras.layers

# this could also be the output a different Keras model or layer
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(400, 400, 1))  # this assumes K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf'
x1 = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(input)
x2 = keras.layers.Flatten()(x1)
x3 = keras.layers.RepeatVector(3)(x2)
x4 = keras.layers.Reshape((200, 200, 3))(x3)
x5 = keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(12,12))(x4)
m = keras.models.Model(input, x5) 
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=m.output, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

but I get an error which I am unsure how to fix.

> builtins.Exception: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Output("input_2:0", shape=(?, 400, 400, 1), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   []

Comment: Unbelievable how there doesn't seem to be any instruction on how to do this.  It seems like the dumbest simplest first thing you'd explain to people, but no.  Keras is cool.  Documentations sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both the Functional API and Sequential approaches to solve this. See working example for both approaches below:

```
from keras.applications.ResNet50 import ResNet50
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, Flatten, RepeatVector, Reshape, ZeroPadding2D, Input, Dense

pretrained = ResNet50(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# Sequential method
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(400, 400, 1)))
model_1.add(Flatten())
model_1.add(RepeatVector(3))
model_1.add(Reshape((200, 200, 3)))
model_1.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(12,12)))
model_1.add(pretrained)
model_1.add(Dense(1))

# functional API method
input = Input(shape=(400, 400, 1))
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(400, 400, 1))(input)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = RepeatVector(3)(x)
x = Reshape((200, 200, 3))(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(12,12))(x)
x = pretrained(x)
preds = Dense(1)(x)

model_2 = Model(input,preds)

model_1.summary()
model_2.summary()
```

The summaries (replace resnet for xception):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
average_pooling2d_1 (Average (None, 200, 200, 1)       0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 40000)             0
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVecto (None, 3, 40000)          0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 200, 200, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
xception (Model)             (None, 7, 7, 2048)        20861480
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 7, 7, 1)           2049
=================================================================
Total params: 20,863,529
Trainable params: 20,809,001
Non-trainable params: 54,528
_________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 400, 400, 1)       0
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_2 (Average (None, 200, 200, 1)       0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 40000)             0
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_2 (RepeatVecto (None, 3, 40000)          0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 200, 200, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPaddin (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
xception (Model)             (None, 7, 7, 2048)        20861480
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 7, 7, 1)           2049
=================================================================
Total params: 20,863,529
Trainable params: 20,809,001
Non-trainable params: 54,528
_________________________________________________________________
```

Both approaches work fine. If you plan on freezing the pretrained model and letting pre/post layers learn -- and afterward finetuning the model, the approach I found to work goes like so:

```
# given the same resnet model as before...
model = load_model('modelname.h5')

# pull out the nested model
nested_model = model.layers[5] # assuming the model is the 5th layer

# loop over the nested model to allow training
for l in nested_model.layers:
  l.trainable=True

# insert the trainable pretrained model back into the original
model.layer[5] = nested_model
```